# Order collection based on relation count Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Dear all i was wondering how can i order this collection of data through a relationship

i have a model called Customer where customer can have many reservations

i get my collection like this

```
Customer::where('tid' , $tid)
 ->with(['reservations'])
 ->paginate(20)
```

while reservations is relation in Customer model and it is hasMany

my question what if i have a filter with two options

1. order by maximum reservations
2. order by minimum reservations

**How i can order those customers by their interactions according to those reservations**

i can attach a filter to the query like this

```
->when($request->get('reservation_filter') != null  , function($q) use($request){
   if($request->get('reservation_filter') == 'order by maximum reservations'){
       // my query here 
   }else{
      // my query here 
   } 
   
})
```

Comment: I am not sure how to do it with a filter but have you tried something like: Customer::where('tid' , $tid)->withCount('reservations')->orderBy('reservations_count', 'desc')->paginate(20); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change order of results based on filter:

```
$sortingOrder = ('order by maximum reservations' == $request->get('reservation_filter'))
    ? 'desc'
    : 'asc';

Customer::where('tid', $tid)
    ->withCount('reservations')
    ->orderBy('reservations_count', $sortingOrder)
    ->paginate(20);
```